# using static slideshowextender method, for multiple users

Tags: c#

I am basically trying to display a set of images stored on a webserver to users via Ajax SlideShowExtender.

I am just wondering how best to approach this, since the function it uses to retrieve the images to display, is a static method. But this site can be used concurrently by 3 different accounts, each of which will have their own set of images to display.

I have always stayed away from static variables and methods whenever doing websites if possible when working with users and individual data.I am worried there will be issues with the slides returned to each account being mixed up due to method being static.

Now obviously I will have to test this fully and check if this will be happening, but is there a better approach to this, or a way to ensure each user is always working with their own set of slides? I was thinking of passing an argument to the method perhaps for each user, but not sure how I would use this to ensure each user gets correct images? See below for basic function that returns slides to slideshowextender:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod]
public static Slide[] GetImages(int userID)
{
    List<Slide> slides = new List<Slide>();

    /* here there is a try catch to read all images from specific directory and add to slides[] */

   return slides.ToArray()
}
```

Comment: this should be fine as long as you are passing in the correct userID and as long as you are not storing data in a static variable...then you should be fine. creating ajax calls using webmethod like you are is only achieved by having a static method.

Comment: Okay thank you. However I have now just realised I would need to use a QueryString to pass this userID parameter. I had these stored in a session variable. I wanted to avoid using QueryString. Thanks for your advice,